# Send JSON using curl from bash script when JSON path supplied as variable

Tags: bash, curl

I just cannot understand why all my attempts failing. I try to use curl to send POST request with json to specific url when a path to JSON defined as variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

JSON_TMP=/home/aaa/jsons/make_6h_from_1h.json
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "@${JSON_TMP}" http://some-url
```

Whatever I tried (putting `"@${JSON_TMP}"` or `"@$JSON_TMP"` or `@"${JSON_TMP}"` or whatever else) just does not seems to work!

What is more annoying is that there are no any error messages or something - I just run command and get prompt back again. On other end I can see that no json was sent.

Comment: Were you trying to use JsonPath in your url?

Comment: "_just does not seems to work_" - is there an error on the server side? What about the query doesn't work? Does `-v` give you more information?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
body_arg=(--data-binary @${filePath})

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${body_arg[@]}"  http://some-url
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary --data-binary @${JSON_TMP} http://some-url
```

Try with removing double quotes across @${JSON_TMP}